# VSCode Typescript intellisense wrong

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

I have been trying to create ServiceWorker for my website using SvelteKit, but am running into an issue here. I created a file `/src/service-worker.ts` and in there, I put the following code

```
import { build, files, prerendered, version } from '$service-worker';

const applicationCache = `applicationCache-v${version}`;
const staticCache = `staticCache-v${version}`;

const returnSSRpage = (path) =>
  caches.open("ssrCache").then((cache) => cache.match(path));

// Caches the svelte app (not the data)
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      caches
        .open("ssrCache")
        .then((cache) => cache.addAll(["/"])),
      caches
        .open(applicationCache)
        .then((cache) => cache.addAll(build)),
      caches
        .open(staticCache)
        .then((cache) => cache.addAll(files))
    ])
      .then(self.skipWaiting()),
  )
})
... reduced code
```

When running `npm run build` this code compiles perfectly fine and the code runs in the browser. However, my VSCode intellisense gets some stuff wrong. Most notably, it says that the `waitUntil` property of `event` does not exist.
`Property 'waitUntil' does not exist on type 'Event'.ts(2339)` among other things, such as `Property 'skipWaiting' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)` and `Cannot find name 'clients'.ts(2304)`.

Now, I am quite new to Javascript and Typescript, but from my experience, the Intellisense should not output an error that doesn't also appear during compilation. Why does this happen?

I am unsure of what information to provide. My TS version is 4.7.4 which is also the version VSCode is using for Intellisense. I have installed the ESLint extension for JS and TS.

What could be the problem here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `"WebWorker"` to the [`compilerOptions.lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) in `tsconfig.json` and declare the type of `self` in the service worker file:

```
declare var self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

This will lead to the event types automatically being inferred without further annotations via the event name.

You may need to restart the TS server (there is a command for that: `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`).

Still, odd that it would build as is...

Comment: Oh nice!!,  I wish I could have found this info before..  I'll delete my answer as I've just updated my code for this way.. :)

Comment: Oh that seems to help! However, this solution still seems to work, even if I don't add the "WebWorker" to tsconfig.json and only use the declare function.
Also, another piece of code (another event.waitUntil, but with two parameters now) is complaining that it expects 1 but got 2 parameters. However, it still compiles... What could be the issue there?

Comment: @DutchEllie Your build might not be checking the types correctly or at all. `waitUntil` only takes one argument, anything beyond the first one will simply be ignored at run time.

Comment: @DutchEllie  You seem to have put an extra comma at the end ->  `.then(self.skipWaiting()),`   Although for me that does not error, are you using something like ESLint?, and it sees this as an extra param?

Comment: @Keith: Trailing commas like this one will not be considered a separate argument, so this is not the location of the referenced error. (Code is abridged)

Comment: @H.B. I think I solved it by just wrapping that stuff also in another Promise.all, seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Keith I removed that, but also removed the braces from the skipWaiting, now there are no more errors!

Comment: @H.B.  Yeah, like I pointed out, it's not erroring for me,.. But if the OP is using something like TSLint, etc.  If might be just a linting error.  Personally I don't bother with ES/TSLint, as Typescripts error checking seem plenty good.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked very well for me:

```js
const sw: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope = self as unknown as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

Now you replace `self` with `sw`, which kinda makes more sense, and also you get correct types.